# JSON String not getting to the server (should be easy to solve if you know express js)

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express js but for some reason, the server is logging an empty object `{}` instead of the actual JSON string that I sent. I have worked with so many other technologies like flask, this makes no sense.

Code:

```
function upload () {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/chat", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: "Deska",
            email: "deska@gmail.com",
            phone: "342234553"
        })
    }).then(result => {
        // do something with the result
        console.log("Completed with result:", result);
    }).catch(err => {
        // if any error occured, then catch it here
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

---

```
app.post('/chat', function(req, res) {

let test = req.body;
console.log(test);
}
```

On the "upload" function I do not get the anything logged, and in the server, I get the an empty object `{}` I mentioned.

If you are to know my issue, I would appreciate help.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

Issue should be in the prontend, as sending the post request with postman works.

Comment: @WiseEye what??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error could be happening because you are missing the `Content-Type` header. You could try this:

```
function upload () {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/chat", {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }, 
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: "Deska",
            email: "deska@gmail.com",
            phone: "342234553"
        })
    }).then(result => {
        // do something with the result
        console.log("Completed with result:", result);
    }).catch(err => {
        // if any error occured, then catch it here
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

You should also make sure that in your server you are using the `express.json` middleware, this way:

```
app.use(express.json());
```